# Red Hat Developer: Subscription Attachment

Tags: linux, redhat, subscription, rhel7

I installed RHEL7 for developers (NO-Cost subscription) and registered it with my username and password for the customer portal , however it doesn't want to attach the subscription. [image: That's the error]

So in order to do it manually I need to run the following command

```
subscription-manager attach --pool=YourID
```

And in order to find my ID I have to run the command

```
subscription-manager list --available
```

Which returns

> No available subscription pools to list

I logged in in my account on developers.redhat.com and it says:[image]

But on the customer panel it says I don't have any active subscriptions

What am I doing wrong?

**Thank you in advance!!**

Comment: contact redhat support?

Comment: I can't! When I try to start a discussion the page says ACCSESS DENIED:

Comment: you don't have the permission to access this page

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on http://unix.stackexchange.com  OR http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

try :

$ subscription-manager register

put your username and password then :

$ subscription-manager attach --auto

Should say something like:

Installed Product Current Status :

Product Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Status: Subscribed

Comment: I get this:# subscription-manager attach --auto
Installed Product Current Status:
Product Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
Status:       Not Subscribed

Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to update your system time, using `sudo chronyc makestep` to update.

And then use `subscription-manager list --consumed` to check the status.

Answer (score 0):

+1. The registration command is:

## subscription-manager register --username= --password=

Are you installing on bare metal or vm?  There are options here: https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/hello-world/

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar troubles.  Here's what I found worked for me.

RHEL offers a no-cost subscription for developers which has to be renewed yearly.

So for me, I had an expired subscription.  To renew, I had to log into access.redhat.com and find expired subscriptions.  There should be a link to  'renew'; it can take a few minutes for to re-activate.

After this I could re-register my system and find subscriptions.